# Symfony3.4 Sonata Admin multi language site, Entity validation with more than 2 fields as unique

Tags: validation, symfony-3.4

How can I validate an Entity with more than 2 fields as unique
I know that sonata admin does not support the default Symfony validation rules  directly but through its own inline validation (errorElement).

see :  https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/conditional_validation.html

I end up with my own solution but not efficient, if any one found a better solution it would be great.

*asssume*

1. The Entity is ArticleTranslation
2. The repository is declared as service
3. multilanguage site
4. title, locale are unique

`
    use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

```
public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $repo = $container->get('app.repository.article_translation');
    $em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('App\ArticleBundle\Entity\ArticleTranslation');

        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->select('a')
                    ->from('ArticleBundle:ArticleTranslation', 'a')
                    ->andWhere('a.title = :title')
                    ->andWhere('a.locale = :locale')
                    ->setParameter('title', $this->getForm()->get('title')->getData())
                    ->setParameter('locale', $this->request->getLocale());

        if ($this->isCurrentRoute('edit')) {/* this will avoid checking the one which is being edited */
                $query  
                    ->andWhere('ft.translatable != :id' )
                    ->setParameter('id', $this->getSubject()->getId());
        }

        $article = $query  
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getOneOrNullResult();


        if ($article) { // check if the article is already exist
            $errorElement
                ->with('title')
                    ->addViolation('This title is already exist')
                ->end()
            ;
        }
}
```

result:
!https://imageshack.com/a/img921/3005/1Qkh0x.png

> any comments ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [UniqueEntity Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) here.

In your ArticleEntity, simply add:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"title", "locale"},
 *     message="This title already exists."
 * )
 */
```

And you should get the correct error message in a much lighter way that what you've done.

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer, but this does not work for me,
check this link pls
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3256